# How to create weighted average of dataset per date?

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I have a dataset,`df` that looks as follows:

| Date | Code | Population | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1000 | 10000 | 5000 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1000 | 10000 | 5013 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2200 | 33000 | 10022 |
| 2021-01-02 | 2200 | 33000 | 10002 |

I would like to take the daily weighted average of my dataframe, where my weight is my `Population`, and store it in a new dataset, `df_avg` that contains only `Date` and `WEIGHTED QTY`. How can I do that?

Comment: what's the expected output, as in, what is the number for Date==2021-01-01 from your sample data?

Comment: @QuangHoang it would be = [(5000*10000) + (10022*33000)]/(10000+33000), or the sum of the products of population times quantity divided by total population

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways: 1) `groupby.apply` with `np.average` and 2) manually calculate with lazy groupby.

Path 1 is easier to code, but a little slower:

```
df.groupby('Date')\
  .apply(lambda x: np.average(x['QTY'], weights=x['Population']))\
  .reset_index(name='avg')
```

Path 2 is faster, but more verbose:

```
df['prods'] = df['QTY'] * df['Population']

groups = df.groupby('Date')

groups['prods'].sum().div(groups['Population'].sum()).reset_index(name='avg')
```

Either way gives you the output:

```
         Date          avg
0  2021-01-01  8854.093023
1  2021-01-02  8841.767442
```

**Note**, an alternative to Path 2 without adding new column to data involves groupby twice:

```
df['QTY'].mul(df['Population']).groupby(df['Date']).sum()\
   .div(df.groupby('Date')['Population'].sum())\
   .reset_index(name='avg')
```

Another option, involving the pipe method:

```py
(df
.assign(weighted_qty = df.Population * df.QTY)
.groupby('Date')
.pipe(lambda df: df.weighted_qty.sum()/df.Population.sum())
)
Date
2021-01-01    8854.093023
2021-01-02    8841.767442
dtype: float64
```